# Getting started with OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

With apologies for this basic question...

I have installed a legacy version of OpenMDAO using pip ("pip install openmdao==1.7.4). How do I now proceed to activate an OpenMDAO environment?

Previously I installed OpenMDAO using the setup script go-openmdao-0.xx.x.py which created a folder "openmdao-0.xx.x". To activate the OpenMDAO virtual environment after this previous installation, I ran ". bin/activate" from this folder. However after installing OpenMDAO using pip the folder is not created & I am unsure what to do next.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenMDAO V1 and V2 you don't have to activate anything. OpenMDAO V0 used a different kind of installation environment. Now you just pip install OpenMDAO into your python environment and then you can run it directly.